# VB crystal Report unable to print

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have been stuck over an issue for days . Here is my condition :- 
Whenever I try to print a report in my module the error is thrown . My printer set up is all good and printing everything else .  Being a new bee I dunno what to do Have tried everything I could do .Please help me . Thanks In advance . Is there something I could register for this  :-

Error is :- Unable to Preview/Print Report.Please check your login Information .

Comment: There is tooo little information you give to us to help you.

Comment: what kinda more information i may provide . I have an exe within my 64 bit Win7 . CRPE32 is going all good . Also there is no issue with crviewer9 :( .

Comment: Can anyone provide me with pdsodbc.dll direct download link

Comment: You report tables have correct login information?  
Are you using correct data providers?  
*Sample: If you are use SQLNCLI provider to obtains data for your report in develop machine you need change to OLEDB for production or install SQLServer client in users pc.

Comment: I am using OLEDB and my connection settings is all good

Answer (score 0):

Finally find it myself . What you need to do is :-

1. Install Crystal Report on the server you want to view your report .
2. Now Open up your report
3. Go to the tab DATABASE
4. Select show SQL query
5. Click ok . Then click Advanced .
6. Select your Server ,WorkStation ID , Language prefernce and database name according to the DSN you     set .
7. Finally Click OK .
8. Now Again go to Database tab and click on the option verify Databases .
9. Click ok .The dialague should open showing databases up to date .If it is not then there must be some change in the procedure call of your database .
10. Click ok . Finally Save your Report .
11. Now Launch Your application . You will see it is working .

What happens back behind is that your server needs an environment to run your crystal report . You might have coded to keep all things dynamic but what happens is crystal report is unable to pick up your workstation ID dynamically without an enviroment that needs to be established by the compiler .